# Comparing statistically significant difference in time series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

As the title sums it up well, I own two series. I need to know if the two are significantly different. Both series have the same temporal granularity. In a quick search, I saw that I could use the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff (KS) test. But I also saw that it compares the distribution. Therefore, I was in doubt whether or not I could use it for this purpose.

I also saw other possible tests like wilcox, or mann witnhey U

Comment: What is the real world question you want to answer? Maybe show us aplot of the two series ...

Comment: I need to know only if the two series are the same, or, have or not significative diffrence